# Registration condition not working? Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make registration activity without using SQLite in android. 
In which user enters data at run time and if he do not fill all sections then user will not proceed to another activity. But the problem is if user is not entering anything then its also proceeding to another activity. 
here is my code. Plz help me whats the error.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText us = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.us);
                EditText pas = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pas);
                EditText em = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.em);
                EditText ph = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ph);
                String UserName=  us.getText().toString();
                String Email=  em.getText().toString();
                String Password=  pas.getText().toString();
                String PhoneNo=  ph.getText().toString();
                us.getEditableText().toString();
                em.getEditableText().toString();
                pas.getEditableText().toString();
                ph.getEditableText().toString();

                 if ((us != null) && (em != null) && (pas != null) &&(ph != null)){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SendOfferActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
                    builder1.setMessage("Enter Valid Information.");

                    builder1.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });


                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();
                }
            }});
    }
```

Comment: Please post logcat ..

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is if user is not entering anything then its also
>   proceeding to another activity. here is my code

you are just checking if the object are not null, but what you want really check is if the `EditText`s contain something. You use

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(am.getText().toString()) /* do the same for the other */) {

}
```

to check the content of your `EditText`s

Answer (score 0):

You are just checking the **EditText** elements and you show test if the user typed something.

```
String usTxt  = us.getText().toString();
String emTxt  = em.getText().toString();
String pasTxt = pas.getText().toString();
String phTxt  = ph.getText().toString();
if (!usTxt.isEmpty() && !emTxt.isEmpty() && !pasTxt.isEmpty() && !phTxt.isEmpty())
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((!UserName.isEmpty()) && (!Email.isEmpty()) && (!Password.isEmpty() &&(!PhoneNo.isEmpty())){}
```